# Api Instance of 'FixturesByDateModel'

Tags: flutter, dart, rapidapi

[image]

This is my API call when `print jsonResponse` it show data after `fromjson` it show me this error:

> Api Instance of 'FixturesByDateModel'

Facing error only in this line of code:

```
FixturesByDateModel data = FixturesByDateModel.fromJson(jsonResponse);
```

Comment: Please post the code as a text, ant an screenshot.